# Include param as part of the data in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-router

I'm trying a new translation mechanism whereby as part of the routes I send in the data what the translated would be in order to get different URLs for a multi language application. For example I would have:

```
{
    path: 'bookings',
    data: { translation: 'reservas' },
    loadChildren: './booking/booking.module#BookingModule'
},
```

that way I can redirect correctly a fixed navbar with different language options and keep the "same url" that makes sense. In order to do so I have the following code:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
        this.router.events.pipe(filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
        , map(() => {
          let child = this.activatedRoute.firstChild;
          while (child) {
            if (child.firstChild) {
              child = child.firstChild;
            } else if (child.snapshot.data && child.snapshot.data['translation']) {
              return child.snapshot.data['translation'];
            } else {
              return null;
            }
          }
          return null;
        })).subscribe( (t: string) => {
             this.translatedUrl = t
        });
    }
```

When I then click on the element to swap language I do a replace of the current URL route with its translation if that makes sense.

The first problem I have is that when I have params I'm not able to handle them correctly because I don't know a way to get them from a component that is already rendered therefore I don't know how to get "refreshed" the `activatedRoute` that could potentially use. Alternatively, I don't know if you include that information as part of the data object, I mean, having something like this:

```
{
    path: ':id',
    data: { translation: 'something', id: ':id' },
    loadChildren: './something/something.module#SomethingModule'
},
```

And obviously my second question is that given all this code, I don't know if there is an easier way of achieving this.

**UPDATE:**

The only other alternative I have thought about is making every component to send data to a shared service with the relevant information. However I reuse some of them in different places and relative urls may be difficult to handle. I thought that configuring everything in the routing would be the place to go

Comment: Inject an instance of `ActivatedRoute` in your component. The attribute `paramMap` is an observable you can subscribe to to get the changing values of the route params.

Comment: I don't think that will work since I'm doing all that from an external component that is already rendered in the screen. All changes happen in an inner router-outlet therefore my goal is to get all the changes happening on external components /routes being rendered somehow. Does that make sense?

Comment: I don't think I follow. If a component is rendered, then any changes it makes to the route or any changes another component makes to the route will be visible to it through the `ActivatedRoute`. If the component isn't rendered, then it effectively doesn't exist, right?

Comment: So, i just want to be sure if i understands you correctly. You want to send your lang object in your routing file as data object? Then you want to subscribe to some parameter in this data object to change lang dynamically on your website. If I am correct i would like to discourage this idea. Use service for that or use Angular build in translation mechanism https://angular.io/guide/i18n

Comment: @lemek I think you're right. Much easier to use a service for this purpose. Thanks for the comment. Alessandro Power, the component I want to communicate with is already rendered. There are URL changes happening because of an inner router-outlet, that's why I have the problems.